# Simple Js program comes up NaN and objectHtmlSpanElement

Tags: javascript, html

I want the hashs and btc both to show up as 1, but the btc shows up as NaN
and the hashs show up as [object HTMLSpanElement]

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <style>
    </style>
    
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
    <pre> </pre>
    <div class="container">
    
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card bg-primary">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
     <i class="fab fa-btc" height="32" width ="32"></i>
     <p class="card-text">Satoshis: <span id="btc"></span></p>
     
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-warning">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <p class="card-text">Hashs: <span id="hashs"></span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-success">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <p class="card-text">a</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-danger">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <p class="card-text">a</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
    <pre> </pre>
    <center>make me a css button to start mining </center>
    </body>
    
    
    
    
    <script>
    var btc = Number(localStorage.getItem("btc") || "1");
    var btc = Number(localStorage.getItem("hashs") || "1");
    
    function update() {
      document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = btc;
      document.getElementById('hashs').innerHTML = hashs;
      localStorage.setItem("btc", btc);
      localStorage.setItem("hashs", hashs);
    }
    
    update();
    
    document.getElementById('ao').onclick = function () {
     btc++;
      update();
    }
    document.getElementById('hash').onclick = function () {
     hashs++;
      update();
    }
    // <button id="ao">Add One</button>
    </script>
    
    
    
    </html>
```

Comment: You have `var btc` twice, probably meant to have one of those as `var hashs`. Also do not use junk text to fill the question out, the editor requires a certain amount of text for a reason.

Comment: The problem is that your global variables have the same names as element IDs. Element IDs are automatically turned into global variables that contain the element.

Comment: @PatrickEvans ok they both come up as NaN now.

Comment: Did you clear localStorage before trying again? You are getting NaN now probably due to having the old values stored

Comment: @Barmar I dont understand, pleas put a answer

Comment: ok @PatrickEvans u help me yay thanks

Comment: You have `<span id="btc">`, so when you use the variable `btc` it refers to that span, not the number you read from localStorage.

Comment: Either change your variable name or the ID so they're not the same. Or put your code inside an IIFE and declare local variables.