# how do I add to a localstoarge variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have my btc and hashs, and when I click start mining, I want it to have every 1 second it adds btc to my balance equal to the number of hashs I have, so if I have 1 satoshi, and 1 hash and I spend 1 second mining, I get 2 btc, then , then 4.

Also can you guys check and make sure I put my timers the right way?

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
</style>

</head>


<body>
<pre> </pre>
<div class="container">

  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card bg-primary">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
    <i class="fab fa-btc" height="32" width ="32"></i>
    <p class="card-text">Satoshis: <span id="btc"></span></p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-warning">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <p class="card-text">Hashs: <span id="hashs"></span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-success">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <p class="card-text">upgrades button here with popup tab</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-danger">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <p class="card-text"><p id="btcmina"><button type="button" onclick="btcmining()" class="btn btn-light">Begin Mining</button></p></p>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
<pre> </pre>
<div class="container">

  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card bg-primary">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
    <i class="fab fa-monero" height="32" width ="32"></i>
    <p class="card-text">monotoshis here</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-warning">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <p class="card-text">mono hashs here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-success">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <p class="card-text">upgrades button here with popup tab</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-danger">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <p class="card-text">Start mining button here with css button</p>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>

</body>




<script>
var btc = Number(localStorage.getItem("btc") || "1");
var hashs = Number(localStorage.getItem("hashs") || "1");

function btcmining() {
    document.getElementById('btcmina').innerHTML = "<p id=mini><button type=button class=btn btn-primary onclick=stopbtc()>Stop Mining</button></p>";

    updateTimer = setTimeout(updatey, 1000000)
        minebtcTimer = setTimeout(btcmining, 1000);
}

function update() {
  document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = btc;
  document.getElementById('hashs').innerHTML = hashs;
  localStorage.setItem("btc", btc);
  localStorage.setItem("hashs", hashs);
}
function updatey() {
  document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = btc;
  document.getElementById('hashs').innerHTML = hashs;
  localStorage.setItem("btc", btc);
  localStorage.setItem("hashs", hashs);
  btcmining()
}
function stopbtc() {
    document.getElementById('mini').innerHTML = "<p id=btcmina><button  type=button onclick=btcmining() class=btn btn-primary>Begin Mining</button></p>"
    clearTimeout(updateTimer);
    clearTimeout(minebtcTimer);
}
update();

/*document.getElementById('ao').onclick = function () {
    btc++;
  update();
}
document.getElementById('hash').onclick = function () {
    hashs++;
  update();
}*/
// <button id="ao">Add One</button>
</script>



</html>
```

Comment: You still haven't fixed the variable name vs. ID conflict in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844412/simple-js-program-comes-up-nan-and-objecthtmlspanelement)

Comment: But that is not issue im having right now, @Barmar how do I add to a variable that is localstorage?

Comment: Read the variable from localstorage into a variable. Add to that variable. Write the variable to localstorage.

Comment: @Barmar idk how to do that.

Comment: Which step don't you understand?

Comment: `variable = variable + 1` adds to the variable.

Comment: @Barmar all please put a answer

Comment: but btc = btc + hash wont work I tried it

Comment: ok but now it is adding massive amounts of numbers and slowing down page @Barmar

Comment: 1 function call every second shouldn't slow it down. You must be starting too many of them.

Comment: here is my new code: https://pastebin.com/33NwWZH3

Comment: Every time you click on the Begin Mining button you start another timer, without clearing the old timer.

Comment: can you put what it should be as a answer? @Barmar

Comment: Wait a second. You're using `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`. So nothing is happening every second.

Comment: But why is my stuff being added? @Barmar

Comment: I'm not sure any more.

Comment: Can you fix my code? @Barmar

Comment: Ah, you call `btcmining()` at the end of `updatey()`, so that starts another timer. But it should still just run once every second, not many times.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem you're having. I can't see any reason why it would be overloading.

Comment: I figured it out @Barmar my timer kept looping over and over. Now I got it not too overload but it starts at 1 then 2 then 3 then 5, then keeps increasing, but still problem not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Read the number from local storage, add to it, then store the new number back in local storage.

```
setInterval(add_to_localstorage, 1000);

function add_to_localstorage() {
    var btc = Number(localStorage.getItem("btc") || "1");
    btc = btc + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("btc", btc);
}
```

This just adds `1`, if you want to add something else you can replace that line with whatever calculations you actually want to do, such as counting the number of hashes and adding that.

Comment: but my thing adds too many numbers now, it adds tens of thousands and slows down page